# Executable file from R code

Tags: linux, r, windows, ubuntu, exe

I'm a master student, and I've a little problem with a script written in R.

How can I produce an executable file from it?

Should I use Linux (e.g.Ubuntu) or windows? I wrote a code in Windows, but I can use Ubuntu.

Comment: R is an interpreted language. You'll always need the interpreter to run the scripts. You can call R from C code, but I don't think that's what you are asking.

Comment: Why do you need an executable file?

Comment: You cannot create an executable from an R script.  The question is a duplicate anyway so I'll close it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using linux, you can run your Rscript from the command line (in the terminal like this)

```
 Rscript <name of your Rscript file>
```

Comment: thanks. i'll try. but, than, how can I use it in R? The question is best reformuled in this terms: what's the usage of .exe file for a Rscript?

Comment: Your follow-up question makes no sense whatsoever.